# Is there experimental evidence for determinism?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, experimental-physics, determinism

In their [2009 Free Will Lectures](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLRazWUD7x-8dWRoTrm8G-47EZ71M45amc), [John Horton Conway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Horton_Conway) claimed that there is no evidence for determinism. Specifically, in [the sixth lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IgvkhgE1Cps), around 38 minutes in, Conway says:

> This is perhaps the most contentious thing that I have to say: there is no evidence for determinism! This absolutely shocked me, and if any of you find it shocking, I hope you go through the education process that I went through.

This shocked me, too. **Is there experimental evidence for determinism?**

Comment: *"Is there experimental evidence for determinism?"* What do you mean by "determinism"? If you drop an apple it falls. It falls every time... is that "evidence of determinism"? If you measure the position of an electron, you measure a real number every time, but it is different pretty much every time. But, the overall measurement pattern en masse behaves deterministically in that you can measure the same pattern every time...

Comment: In more technical terms, Newton's laws are deterministic and are well established as a good description of classical phenomena. In quantum mechanics some determinism (e.g., of the wave function itself) is preserved, but some determinism is lost (e.g., the measurement can "collapse" to any single real value and those real values are described probabilistically by the wave function if the experiment is repeated)...

Comment: This is a good question, but it is a question of philosophy, not physics.

Comment: @MattHanson Asking for **experimental** evidence for determinism is genuine physics.  Please, do not be afraid by the word determinism. Would you classify *deterministic chaos* as a philosophical subject?

Comment: @hft As soon *as some determinism is lost*, the theory cannot be considered deterministic. We can argue that it keeps some deterministic element in part, but that is just a specific qualification of an intrinsically nondeterministic theory. BTW, I do not understand what clarification this question would need. In its present form, it asks for experimental evidence for determinism. I do not see what additional clarification could be looked for.

Comment: You are right that asking for experimental evidence is valid. Unfortunately, this question was rather unclear on that specific point. I’m certainly not afraid of this discussion, I just want to keep philosophical musings off of a site for pure physics.

Comment: @GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 I agree. However, if one only thinks about Newtonian Mechanics then it sure *seems* very much like the world is deterministic. That's all I'm saying.

Comment: @MattHanson: I've clarified the question. I could ask a similar question on Philosophy SE, something like "is there provable argumentation for determinism?" but I am not optimistic about receiving high-quality answers there; more importantly, I want to know about experimental evidence, not argumentation.

Comment: Determinism is a property of theories, not nature. There is evidence that deterministic models work (classical physics). There is also evidence that non-deterministic models work (QM).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already mentioned by several answers in one way or another: There is NO evidence for determinism at the quantum level.

1. The predictions of current Quantum Mechanical theory do not yield specific outcomes to individual trials of many experiments.  Those outcomes are random, certainly as best as can be determined by any method of testing randomness.  Certainly, that result is precisely the opposite one would expect if there were factors - hidden or not - that explained each and every outcome.

This article by [Kim et al (2017)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1709.06779) discusses usage of quantum processes to generate random numbers, from the abstract:

*"Quantum mechanics provides means of generating genuine randomness that is impossible with deterministic classical processes."*

2. In nearly 100 years of looking closely, using ever more sophisticated experimental gear looking deep into the nature of the quantum world: there has been not the slightest hint that there is a level in which exists a determinate cause for any random outcome whatsoever.  If you don't think that is strong evidence, you may as well say there is no proof the Loch Ness Monster doesn't exist.
3. Most physicists today believe that quantum mechanics is "complete" (using the meaning of EPR, 1935, "[Can Quantum-Mechanical Description of Physical Reality Be Considered Complete' ?](https://journals.aps.org/pr/pdf/10.1103/PhysRev.47.777)").  In that meaning, there is no deeper theory to be found which would explain the outcomes of probabilistic predictions of current theory.
4. Of course, there are interpretations of QM in which determinism is maintained and locality is discarded.  Bohmian Mechanics is one such.  To date, there is no evidence to support that interpretation over any others.  On the other hand, there are significant issues attempting to develop a relativistic version of such theory.   There are significant reasons to believe that cannot be accomplished.  Of course, Bohmians reject all such arguments.  But here is an example of one such: [Bohm's "quantum potential" can be considered falsified by experiment](https://arxiv.org/abs/1410.2014)
5. While Bell (1964) is considered a powerful weapon against determinism, we also know that its "no-go" against determinism is not absolute.  But a lot has changed since in the way of no-gos.
   a) [Bell-Kochen-Specker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kochen%E2%80%93Specker_theorem) rules out hidden variables.
   b) You also have work such as Gleason, Leggett, Hardy.
   c) And most importantly: the [GHZ Theorem (1989)](https://www.drchinese.com/David/Bell-MultiPhotonGHZ.pdf) appears to rule out both locality and determinism simultaneously.  Individual outcomes of GHZ tests are random, but each and every trial violates local realism.  Many are now coming to the conclusion that both locality AND realism/determinism/hidden variables must be dropped.
6. And finally: Let's all agree to admit that new evidence could appear tomorrow that would change our view.  That's true of anything and everything we know!  Perhaps our sun really is the center of the universe!!  But... no, it's not.  The simple truth: Is there evidence for quantum determinism? None. Is there evidence for indeterminism? Yes, a lot.

Comment: Some "evidence" for (really, a good reason for seeking)  deterministic models is the success of Schroedinger's equation, which is deterministic, and also success of mechanics and EM theory on the macroscale; these would not work if the microscale was completely non-deterministic. When it comes to quantum measurements, these do not manifest complete determinism, but they aren't completely random either. Non-existence of evidence is not evidence of non-existence. No-go theorems describe sets of axioms, not necessarily the real world.

Comment: There really can't be such a thing as evidence of non-existence in the real world, so this question of underlying determinism can only continue to be open indefinitely, or end with a discovery of a deterministic model recovering features of quantum measurements. No-go theorems and experiments conforming to their predictions show such model is very hard to formulate, and one may have to think beyond local models, or beyond naive ideas about independence of the studied system state and the measurement setup.

Comment: @JánLalinský Despite many years of searching by thousands of researchers looking where hidden variables might be expected to exist without any success, and despite multiple no-go theorems, you refuse to call that evidence. Well, it’s evidence. And I would call it “beyond a reasonable doubt” were I on a jury.

Comment: Researchers know there are ignored variables, using them in constructing hidden variable theories is natural. There is a background EM radiation in every experiment ever done, interacting with the system and the measurement apparatus; description of this radiation takes infinite number of parameters, most of which are uncontrollable. What people did try to look for are classical-type theories/models which can reproduce quantum theory features using such additional variables.

Comment: Just because success of these efforts was minuscule so far, this is not evidence of this being an impossible task or wrong. Research of alternative descriptions and questioning orthodox quantum theory at least produced a better understanding of QT itself in case of the Bell-type inequalities. You may have a point in that considering the lackluster results of these activities in revolutionizing our knowledge of physics of particles, atoms and molecules, or in practical applications, such research should not be supported with too much funding.

Comment: @JánLalinský You say: *"There is a background EM radiation in every experiment ... interacting with the system and the measurement apparatus; description of this radiation takes infinite number of parameters..."* We already know all of these, to the extent they exist, completely cancel out. Perfect correlations in Bell tests are absolute proof of that. Measurements on distant entangled systems give 100% expected results on the same measurement basis. Context (future measurement settings) - and nothing else - determines the quantum mechanical expectation value.

Comment: Source on "perfection correlations in Bell tests are absolute proof of that"? Afaik Bell test experiments are not disproofs of any definite nonlocal hidden variable theory, they just show the Bell inequalities are violated.

Comment: @JánLalinský Bell tests require calibration. "Perfect" correlations assure the experimenter that she has aligned everything optimally. Were the lab itself a significant factor, or if the detector itself added anything, you couldn't get perfect correlations and you couldn't violate Bell inequalities by 213 SD. No experiment is ideal, nor does every paper publish calibration data. See graph on pg. 15 of this reference from 2003: https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0303018 The green line is theoretical, look at 0 and 90 degrees for the perfect correlations. The blue/black dots are associated actual.

Comment: > *Were the lab itself a significant factor, or if the detector itself added anything, you couldn't get perfect correlations and you couldn't violate Bell inequalities by 213 SD* You're arguing that knowing something is irrelevant for obtaining the same results of experiments, while I'm arguing for relevance of that something to alternative explanations of those experiments which aim to provide better predictions. The first position is true but does not disprove the second one.

Comment: Great answer, +1. However I think you overlooked 'many worlds' in your treatment of deterministic interpretations of QM.

Comment: @TKoL I didn't mean to exclude MWI specifically, and it is certainly one of the most popular interpretations (more than Bohmian I would say). I would have needed to include it with the Deterministic group due to the Schrödinger equation for evolution of the wave function.  Although it might (im)properly also be placed in the indeterministic column too, since which branch we appear to be in is completely random/unpredictable. :) Which is also a good attribute!

Comment: @DrChinese yeah, i would describe it as 'meta-determinism with subjective randomness'.

Answer (score 5):

Of course, I assume that, in the context of this question, determinism means *physical determinism*.
In a way, the answer is already present in Conway's lecture. It depends on the level of description. We have experimental evidence for determinism at some scale, the one where Classical Mechanics and Electromagnetism work.

When we move to the atomic scale, determinism is not a good model anymore. It is an open question (from the experimental point of view) if the non-deterministic behavior at the atomic scale could be interpreted as a deterministic behavior at a finer scale.

That's the answer one could get from Physics. I would leave aside additional considerations that are interesting but external to physics.

Comment: > *When we move to the atomic scale, determinism is not a good model anymore.* The model there is Schroedinger's equation, and it manifests unique evolution of any initial condition, thus is a deterministic model. The model *is* deficient in that it is not able to predict results of measurements except in special cases. But the model itself is still deterministic, it just determines something that we can't measure and check, and it does not determine those things we can measure and check.

Comment: @JánLalinský You are speaking about Schrodinger's equation.  It is obvious that it is a deterministic evolution equation. However, I am speaking about the measurement and the underlying theory. No doubt that at the present level of understanding, QM introduces a non-determinsitc description.

Comment: Quantum theory introduces description in terms of probabilities, but this description is deterministic in mathematical sense. "Non-deterministic" is just not a good word to refer to quantum theory, this theory is deterministic, it just determines the wrong thing, so the theory is incomplete.

Comment: I really mean the Schroedinger equation. When various other assumptions are added (the well-known ideas about results of measurement), the result is not a deterministic theory because the act of measurement breaks that. But one can use Schroedinger's equation to find many things without ever using those ideas about results of measurement.

Comment: @JánLalinský I agree that "one can use Schroedinger's equation to find many things without ever using those ideas about measurement results. ". Still, classical determinism implies that if we know the system's state at time $t$, we can predict with probability one the outcome of any experiment on that system at time $t'>t$. In this sense, the atomic scale description, at the present level of our understanding, defeats determinism.

Comment: @JánLalinský *"The model there is Schroedinger's equation, and it manifests unique evolution of any initial condition"* This is not really true when you introduce measurements. The *wave function* evolves deterministically (like $U(t,0)|\Psi\rangle$) when no measurement is performed. But, in the usual interpretation of quantum mechanics, when a measurement is perform the wave function collapses to reflect the measured result. This latter evolution of the wave function is not deterministic since we can not know beforehand what value we will measure.

Comment: @hft yes that is the projection postulate, or filtering behaviour of quantum measurements. However it seems to me this is more theory of quantum measurements than quantum theory core; this rule is not as generally useful part of the theory as Schroedinger's equation is. It is a way to get an initial condition for psi function for later times, but usefulness of this is limited to some quantities only, mostly in spin projection and light polarization experiments, where measurements at later times happen.

Comment: @hft When position of an electron (or other particle) is recorded on a detector screen, nobody's work really depends on application of the projection postulate at the time of detection to get psi at later times, because the electron is considered to be lost / has unknown direction and momentum. Even applying the projection postulate here is problematic, because due to finite precision of measurement of continuous variable, the collapse can't result in a zero-width peak. The best we can do is some narrow packet, of unknown width, and who's found what value that width has?

Comment: @GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 Strictly speaking, classical determinism is assuming complete knowledge of the initial condition of the whole world may be needed. But such complete knowledge can never be had in any experiment and thus the idea that the world obeys classical determinism can never be falsified.

Comment: @hft also the case of particles moving in bubble chamber or vapor chamber shows that measurement of position in practice does not follow the projection postulate, because after the record of position is made (bubble, or droplet), the particle continues preferentially in the original direction; the past momentum is not completely forgotten like spin state is in Stern-Gerlach type measurements.

Comment: This answer is a good start. Could you go into more detail about macroscopic experiments which show evidence for determinism? I'm only familiar with classical mechanics, chemistry, and statistical mechanics, which all have reproducible experimental results but only non-deterministically. Mechanical experiments have jitter, chemical experiments have unpredictable mixes of reactants, etc.

Comment: @Corbin This answer is better than "a good start." It is the best answer you will get that is not a lengthy discussion, and guess what else, you were able to eke out a lengthy discussion in the comment. (P.S. Discussions are off topic here.) Your question was off topic and vague and should not receive any other answer other than this, and really should not even receive this answer.

Comment: @Corbin Do not confuse classical probabilistic models with quantum probabilistic models. For example, classical statistical mechanics is probabilistic, but for completely different reasons than quantum mechanics. Because both theories are probabilistic they have some similarities in appearance, but this is nothing "deep." It is just a result of both theories being probabilistic. In quantum mechanics there is no way out of the probabilistic predictions, whereas, in principle (but not in practice), in classical statistical mechanics we "could" track all the "particles" deterministically .

Comment: @hft: I agree and have decided to not accept this answer. For posterity: the answer doesn't give a straight yes/no answer to a yes/no question, nor does it substantiate its soft yes with evidence. It's still a good start!

Comment: @Corbin Not always what people ask as a yes/no question can be answered by a yes/no answer.

Answer (score 2):

Classical physics going from Newton to Einstein is deterministic. It was the advent of quantum mechanics that showed nature had an element of indeterminism.

We can be a bit more precise. The dynamic postulates of QM have a deterministic part and an indeterministic part. The deterministic part says that a quantum property of a system has several possible values which evolve deterministically in such a way that total probability is conserved. The indeterministic part says that on measurement, the system resolves the superposition by choosing one of the possible values randomly.

There is a caveat, we can argue that a possible value that evolves deterministically is not in fact fundamentally deterministic. This means that QM throughout is indeterministic.

That this is still startling shows just how pervasive the notion of determinism is in physics. This is obviously an outcome of the huge success of classical physics. Nevertheless all around us we see indeterminism. And it is this probably why the early philosophers of nature, as referenced by Aristotle in his *Physics*, argued that "chance can be a cause".

Conway is suggesting that free will arises from this indeterminism in nature.

> Is there experimental evidence for free will?

Conway does claim in the video that there is no evidence for free will. In fact he says there is no proof. I am not sure he has thought this through. What is understood by proof and evidence is different in different fields of study. What a law court understands by it is different from a mathematician, and also for a physicist.

As Conway is a mathematician, let us go for the moment, with a mathematicians understanding. Well, this begins with postulates and goes on from there by way of deduction. This is the formalists position. But why do we accept these postulates? On reflection, we see that in fact we choose them for the most part for the consequences that flow from them. Thus there is a dialectic between postulates and consequences. Therefore in what appears to be an efficient cause (this is the conventional notion of cause), we in fact have a final cause. A cause being final when we aim towards an outcome.

Conway appears to take physics as his theory of the natural world. But we are also a part of nature. But generally most people do not consider physics to apply to us and nor to most life. Physicalists, either from an infatuation of physics, or from a lack of imagination, or both, do think it applies.

But a full theory of nature must take us into account. However, all fields of study that takes men and women at its centre, takes it as axiomatic that we have free will. In all such fields, it is such a basic premise that it is not even mentioned, even in passing.

Thus, yes, there is evidence. But is there experimental evidence? Well yes, ask any man or woman whether they are free, and I can guarantee everyone will say yes.

Answer (score 0):

No, but at this level of philosophical skepticism there isn’t experimental evidence for anything (including indeterminism) except my own consciousness.

Comment: There is quite a bit of experimental evidence for indeterminism, particularly from [Bell tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_test).

Comment: @Corbin I disagree, Bell tests do not test indeterminism, but non classical correlations, it is agnostic to the question "can QM can be explained by a deeper  deterministic non local  theory?"

Comment: @PatoGalmarini: The Kochen-Specker theorem put that hope to bed, and there is yet to be any (toy) ontic model of QM which reproduces Bell correlations.

Comment: @Corbin Do you equate "non contextual" with "non deterministic"?

Answer (score -1):

There is no proof of determinism because quantum mechanics seems to have probabilistic aspects so is therefore not completely deterministic, this doesn't prove free will it simply shows that since we don't know why these events happen quantum mechanics is agnostic to determinism, free will, etc. and that the argument that we don't have free will because of determinism is based on classical physics, and as we now know classical physics isn't the end of the conversation. This brings us to two main alternative theories which state that there are hidden variables at play that are deterministic and only give the appearance of probabilistic results, or on the other more mainstream end quantum mechanics is truly governed by non deterministic properties, Therefore whether there is complete determinism in the universe depends on your interpretation of quantum mechanics and consequently there is no solid proof of determinism on a fundamental level.

For more information on the deterministic interpretations of Quantum Mechanics read:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Broglie%E2%80%93Bohm_theory

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden-variable_theory